# Why is my airplane moving only partway and not all the way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, transform

So I've spent 2 days looking over this script, and I still don't see what I did wrong. I want to make a simple AI plane that will fly from one point to another. After arriving on Waypoint 1, it should fly towards Waypoint 2. I'll include my script below:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections

 public class AICustomScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
 //first waypoint
 public Transform Waypoint;
 //second waypoint
 public Transform Waypoint2;


 void Start()
 {
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
 //make plane point in direction of first waypoint
     transform.LookAt(Waypoint);
 }
 //allow me to select amount of force in editor
 public float AddForceAmount;
 //allow me to select plane in editor
 public Rigidbody rb;

/void FixedUpdate()
 {
//make plane move
     rb.AddForce(transform.forward * AddForceAmount);
 }
 //PART OF CODE TO DETECT ARRIVAL ON WAYPOINT
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
     if (other.gameObject)
     {
//destroys waypoint
         Destroy(other.gameObject);
  //makes plane look at 2nd waypoint (Waypoint2)
         transform.LookAt(Waypoint2);
     }
 }
 }

 //SO WHAT'S WRONG?
```

I've included my logical thinking in the comments. However, when the plane arrives at Waypoint 1, it turns toward Waypoint 2, but only partially. So while it is flying towards the 2nd waypoint, it never "hits" it. Why?

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the plane partially turn or partially travel to the waypoint2?

Comment: Yes, but only partially.

Comment: Is the plane's forward vector lined up with the way the plane is pointing?

Comment: I'll post screenshots in a minute, but I think it's "forward vector" is pointing in the way it is flying

Comment: Screenshots, 1st picture is before it hits Waypoint 1, 2nd is after it hits Waypoint 1, 3rd picture shows it flying past Waypoint 2. As you see, it does make a slight dip into the direction of the 2nd point, but not enough to actually hit it :( https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=654B82697E6A9F8F!38714&authkey=!AGdf0zd6odFFZeQ&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: New screenshots, 1st before impact of Waypoint 1, 2nd after impact. They look perfectly aligned to me: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=654B82697E6A9F8F!38717&authkey=!AFpJg_J136ZESaU&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: @Antonnelson have you tried calling transform.LookAt(Waypoint2); more than once while the plane is traveling towards Waypoint2 ?

Comment: Is `Waypoint2` a parent object?

Comment: @user3071284 Waypoint2 is a parent object in the inspector, and it is assigned in the script.

Comment: Here is the new script, made no difference, put it on Pastebin since I'm having issues with SO :/ http://pastebin.com/SW6rCg9G

Comment: @B.I.A yes I have as you see in this new script: http://pastebin.com/SW6rCg9G

Comment: Suppose a body has a particular velocity in one direction. Then you apply a force in another direction. In real world physics, the body may change its direction, but the direction will not be aligned with the force. If you throw a ball to the east then the ball has a force on it pulling it down, but it does not move straight down. It keeps moving to the east as it falls. Is that the case in this physics system as well? You have imparted a velocity to an object; adding a force may change the direction, but not necessarily make the object move in the direction of the force.

Comment: Without a more complete code example, it's impossible to know for certain what the problem is. But it seems likely the main problem is you are _adding_ the force, imposing an acceleration in the facing direction, rather than simply setting the object's `velocity` vector. See the previous comment from Eric for the physical description of the problem. Frankly, it's also not clear why you add the force on every call to `FixedUpdate()`; I'd think that would result in the object continually accelerating, which doesn't seem like what one would want.

Comment: @eric I think you solved the problem on WHY it is not working, however now I need to figure out HOW to fix this.... :(

Comment: @peter thanks, how do I go about fixing this? Sorry for this crude question I'm not very good at c#

Comment: Well, think about what you *want* to happen. When the airplane reaches the first waypoint you could say "airplane velocity is hereby cancelled to zero; now point in the new direction and here's a push in that direction".  This is physically unrealistic. A real airplane pilot would aim for a point away from the first waypoint, begin the turn well before the first waypoint, such that the waypoint was at the apex of the curve, and such that the plane comes out of the turn pointing at the second waypoint. (Assuming it is the last waypoint.)

Comment: The solution you come up with depends entirely on how realistic you want the simulation to feel. A very "cartoon" physics where velocity can be cancelled arbitrarily might be fun and interesting, or it might seem really bad. What kind of simulation is it?

Comment: It is a racing game between 2 high-tech airplanes. I want to game to have a "in the future" feel, so realism isn't as important as interesting gameplay. I just started making it and first I tried Unity's build in NavMeshAgent system but quickly realized it wouldn't work.

Comment: I see; so the AI is the opponent to the human player. You face a number of interesting problems here, and the physics problems are not the hardest. The tricky bit with racing game AIs is to optimize the AI for *player has fun*, and not *AI wins*.  Doing the math so that the AI comes up with the optimal route is tricky, but ultimately pointless; it is no fun to play against such an AI!

Comment: What I would suggest is to give your AI module *the same controls that the player has*, plus full knowledge of the player's actions. If the AI can do tricks that the player cannot, like stopping on a dime and changing direction arbitrarily, that makes the player feel cheated. Now you have the problem of your AI simulating the control movements a human would do to run the course. But you *have* the control movements a human would do to run the course; play the game a few hundred times and *record your actions*.

Comment: I was thinking of having the AI run the course, and change speed according to how far ahead the player is. Also I'd calculate how long it would take the player to catch up to the AI. That way if the player is too far ahead the AI can speed up, vice-versa. Also later I'll implement dropping smoke and missiles which should make things interesting. However I'd want to make the race _as close as possible while having the player almost always win_. And how would I "record my actions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use spherical interpolation to make the airplane face the waypoint while changing its position. instead of adding forward force.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AICustomScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] Waypoints;
    public float minimumTouchDistance = 2.0f; // minimum distance between the airplane and the waypoint
    public float airplaneSpeed = 10.0f;
    private Transform currentWaypoint; // keep track of current waypoint
    private int currentIndex; // current position in the waypoint array

     void Start()
     {
         currentWaypoint = Waypoints[0]; // set initial waypoint
        currentIndex = 0; // set initial index
     }

     void Update()
     {
       faceAndMove();

       if (Vector3.Distance(currentWaypoint.transform.position, transform.position) < minimumTouchDistance)
       {
            currentIndex++;
             if (currentIndex > Waypoints.Length - 1)
             {
                 currentIndex = 0;
             }
            currentWaypoint = Waypoints[currentIndex];
         }
     }

      void faceAndMove()
      {
           Vector3 deltaPosition = currentWaypoint.transform.position - transform.position;
           Vector3 calcVector = deltaPosition.normalized * airplaneSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
           this.transform.position += calcVector;
           this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(deltaPosition), 4 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Code-dump answers are no more useful than code-dump questions. Please improve your answer by adding explanatory text that describes both what the OP did wrong, and how the code you posted rectifies their error.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, but how do I use that code? Bit confused on what it does and how to use it, as Peter said...

Comment: @Antonnelson: Basically this answer is saying that rather than modeling it as a bunch of objects with forces acting on them, rather just divide up the space between the initial position and the waypoint into some number of points along the way and make the airplane simply transition from one point to the next point until the waypoint is hit.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! After editing the code and fixing up the errors it works VERY well and I can't thank you enough as this was the basis of the game. I'll try to understand the script better as many things in it I don't know (such as Quaternion.Slerp and calcVector etc...) but this will be a good educational project for myself :)